# Speed of file transfer from Amzon S3 to EC2/EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-transfer, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I'm working on estimating how long it would take to download 100 GB worth of files from Amazon S3 to an EBS drive.  Assuming both are in the same region, what kind of speed could be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run a few tests on a single 100 MB file and the speed ranged from 8 MB/s to 14 MB/s.  I used cloudberry S3 explorer running on an EC2 micro instance of win server 2008, and numbers come from timing the download (and are similar to what the cloudberry UI was reporting during the download).

Answer (score 0):

The speed does not just depend on your geographic location, but it also depends on an instance type used. E.g. a small instance' interface maxes out at around 25 MBit/second (3.125 MB/s). Larger instances offer more throughput.

Then add to that EBS and its sometimes flakey read/write performance.

The bottom line: *your mileage will vary*. :)

Comment: Good point, I'm sure it will vary.  I was on a micro instance though and was seeing the higher 8 - 14 MB/s.